# Will my tyres fit?

Tags: bmw, wheels, tires

I currently have `225/50R16` run flat tyres on my BMW 3 series 320d E90 (2006) and I am looking to get some new alloys. I'm looking at getting [16 Inch BBS SR alloys](http://www.wheelbasealloys.com/alloy-wheels/bbs/sr/grey/16-inch).

They have a width of `7J` and an offset of `35 to 48`, but is this ok for the size tyres I currently have?

If you could explain how you calculated/got to the answer that would be great.

Any helps appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Make and model of your car?

Comment: @chilljeet I have added this to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked in my handbook and 225's can be fitted on 7J up to 8J, but make sure that you check the offset for your car. The offset relates to the fitment of wheel to car and has no relevance to the tyre itself.